# Do Library Permissions trump Site Permissions?

Tags: permissions, 2016

Given: A User has Read only permission on a site, but has Edit permission on one of the Site's libraries.
Is the User limited to Read-only on the library (per Site permission), or are they able to Edit (per the library permission).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user would have read permission across the site except the library where the user would have edit permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you've broken inheritance of site permissions for the library, the library would look at it's own permissions to determine the rights of the user.